# Klocwork raises warning on make_unique

Tags: c++, unique-ptr, klocwork

I have the following structure,

```
struct MyStruct{
bool myBool,
int myInt,
std::unique_ptr<boost::circular_buffer<int>> myUniquePtr;
} ;
```

Let's say I construct the following object,

```
MyStruct* myStruct = new MyStruct();
```

I then update the size of my buffer with

```
myStruct->myUniquePtr = std::make_unique<boost::circular_buffer<int>>(DIM)
```

where

```
 #define DIM 8
```

It works as expected but my static code analyzer (`Klocwork`) flags the previous line (the one with `make_unique`)

> LOCRET.ARG: Address of local variable is returned through formal
> argument

Details:

> - Local address "&std::make_unique<boost::circular_buffer < int > >(DIM)" is passed through 'operator=' and stored into 'myStruct->myUniquePtr._M_t'
> - 'myStruct->myUniquePtr._M_t' can be used outside of this function

In fact, all lines relying on `make_unique` yield this warning. I am wondering whether it's a false positive or not.

**Minimal Reproducible Example:**

```
struct MyStruct{
        bool myBool,
        int myInt,
        std::unique_ptr<boost::circular_buffer<int>> myUniquePtr;
        } ;

void initMyStruct(MyStruct* pStruct)
{
 pStruct->myUniquePtr = std::make_unique<<boost::circular_buffer<int>>(DIM);
}
```

and as main:

```
MyStruct* myStruct = new MyStruct();
initMyStruct(myStruct);
```

Comment: Why not `boost::circular_buffer<int> myMember;`? There is no much sense in using pointers. Could you post a [mcve]? The shown code has no functions to show.

Comment: And why not initalize that boost::circular_buffer<int> or its unique_pointer in the constructor of the struct (a struct and class are the same thing except for default public/private behavior). There is nothing dynamic about it is always the same size and it is not huge (so will fit on stack if needed).

Comment: @PepijnKramer: In this example yes, it's the same size, but the code (I did not code it from scratch, I got it as is) first constructs objects then initializes it. Historically, it's a pure C code, so it uses C structures and uses pointers (with malloc) to set arrays size during init (sizes are not necessarily known at compile time, they can be read from a config file for example)

Comment: Ok with malloc then initializing members is out of the picture ;) 
I don't understand the klocwork warning either.

Comment: @273K added. I could also get rid of the (smart) pointer but I currently just want to understand the warning origin.

Comment: I've added details from Klocwork

Comment: a compilable code to reproduce the issue  will help to understand the issue better.